# ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound: Couldn't find Player with 'id'=all

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

Player_controller

class PlayersController < ApplicationController

```
def index
    @players = Player.all
end

def show
    @player = Player.find(params[:id])
end 

def new
end

def create
    @player = Player.new(player_params)
    @player.save
    redirect_to @player
end

private
    def player_params
    params.require(:player).permit(:name, :description)
end
```

end

I am trying to display the data stored in the player model, here is my show.html

show.html

**Name:**

**Description:**

The actual player name and description is not displayed on the show action. While trying to debug in the console with `@players = Player.find(:all)`
, here is the error message

```
SELECT  "players".* FROM "players" WHERE "players"."id" = NULL LIMIT 1
ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound: Couldn't find Player with 'id'=all
```

Comment: please post your schema migration for `Players` table.

Comment: class CreatePlayers < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    create_table :players do |t|
      t.string :name
      t.text :description

      t.timestamps null: false
    end
  end
end

Comment: find(:all) is deprecated in latest version of rails.so try using `@players = Player.all`. also post your `show` view.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're using `Player.find(:all)` in the console - [Find expects an id, a list of ids, or an array of ids](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/FinderMethods.html#method-i-find).  You probably want to use `Player.all`.

Comment: Thanks this solved the resolve on the console. But now I am seeing null for all the name and description in the table. Not sure about what I am missing.

Comment: try starting a db console with `rails db` - this should start a mysql or psql prompt, and you can query the db directly.  you may not actually have any data in the db.

Comment: Yeah, thats the exact issue. I am trying to check why the data is not reaching table.

Comment: ok - this seems like a different question, but how did you save the data to the database originally?  why are you expecting it to be there?